# Android - Stop Activity when boolean changed

Tags: android

I've built an app that has this activities LifeCycle:
StartActivity -> TemplateChooseOptions -> ChooseTemplate -> Templates

and i have a class that has boolean in it. the boolean will change when a server error is occurred.

when the boolean change, i want that all the activities will finish exept for Start Activity.
I've tried this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ClientLogic CL = Globals.getInstance().getCL();
        while(!CL.isErrStatus());
        if(CL.isErrStatus()){
            finish();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

but it takes too much CPU power.

what can I do?

Comment: Make a sleep for 2-3 second . `Thread.sleep(2000);` It will help you about the power saving .

Comment: I think, you can use broadcast receiver. Check that too. If It works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a thread, create your own listener and implement it in your activities

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ServerErrorListener {
    @Override
    onServerError() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(ClientLogic.getInstance().getCL().isErrStatus) {
            // Todo finish
        }
        ClientLogic.getInstance().addErrorListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        ClientLogic.getInstance().removeListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Or use a BroadcastReceiver as @mubeen says.